# Partial differential equality

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\} \to$ $\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that   $$      x\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} +  y\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} =f(x,y)$$  everywhere on the punctured plane.

Show that $f=0$ everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$  .

My attempts have been based on looking at the values of $f$ along the $x$, $y$ axis, as well as trying to find a contradiction by computing the partial derivatives of $f$. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familar with the method of characteristics, this very simple case can be solved with another method :

The symetry of $\:x\:$ and $\:y\:$ in the PDE draw us to try a change of function of the kind :
$$f(x,y)=(x+y)g(x,y)$$
$$xf_y+yf_x=x(g+(x+y)g_y)+y(g+(x+y)g_x)=f=(x+y)g$$
$$xg_y+yg_x=0$$
With $\:X=x^2\:$ and $\:Y=y^2\:$ then :
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}=0$$
With any derivable function $\:F\:$ :
$$g=F(X-Y)=F(x^2-y^2)$$
$$f(x,y)=(x+y)F(x^2-y^2)$$

In addition :

Brief application of the method of characteristics.

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{df}{f}$$
First, from $\:\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{x}\:$ leading to :
$$x^2-y^2=C_1$$
Second, from $\:\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dx+dy}{x+y}=\frac{d(x+y)}{(x+y)}=\frac{df}{f}\:$ leading to :
$$\frac{f}{(x+y)}=C_2$$
The general solution of the PDE, expressed on implicit form, with any differentiable function $\:\Phi\:$ , is :
$$\Phi\left(\frac{f}{(x+y)}\:,\:x^2-y^2\right)=0$$
which, with any derivable function $\;F\:$ , is equivalent to : $\:\frac{f}{(x+y)}=F(x^2-y^2)$
$$f=(x+y)F(x^2-y^2)$$